# How to get term child?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have three level categories in my Wordpress site.
It's looks like:

```
 Parent A
  - Child A1
     - - Child child A11
     - - Child child A12
  - Child A2
     - - Child child A21
     - - Child child A22
Parent B
  - Child B1
     - - Child child B11
     - - Child child B12
  - Child B2
    - - Child child B11
    - - Child child B12
```

I have a code:

```
<?php
        $termID = 3; // Parent A ID
        $taxonomyName = "products";
        $termchildren = get_term_children( $termID, $taxonomyName );
            echo'<div class="sub"> <div class="links">';
              foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
                  $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
                  echo'<a href="#">' . $term->name . '</a>';}
            echo'</div> </div>';?>
```

The result of the code is:

- Child A1
- Child child A11
- Child child A12
- Child A2
- Child child A21
- Child child A22

How to get only the Child without Child Child?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try

```
$termchildren = get_terms( $taxonomyName, ['child_of'=>$termID, 'parent'=>$termID]);
```

instead of

```
$termchildren = get_term_children( $termID, $taxonomyName );
```

If the `child_of` and `parent` values are same then the result will be only one level.